# Set variable equal to value based on match in bash

Tags: bash

I have a script where I want to set a variable equal to a specific value based on a match from a file (in bash).

For example:

File in .csv contains:

```
Name,ID,Region
Device1,1,USA
Device2,2,UK
```

I want to declare variables at the beginning like this:

```
region1=USA
regions2=UK
region3=Ireland
etc...
```

Then, whilst reading the csv, I need to match the `Region`column's name to the global variable set at the beginning of a file, to then use this in an API. So if a device in the csv has a region set of USA, I should be able to use `region1` during the update call in the API. I want  to use a `while` loop to iterate over the csv file line by line, and update each device's region.

Does anyone maybe know how I can achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: This is not a homework assignment before anyone asks :-)

Comment: Hi, what did you try to achieve this? Could you please show what you tried?

Comment: To be brutally honest, I am in a sort-of "mind-loop" here. I know I can do it with a series of if-else statements, but that would end up as 8 different if-else statements. I was hoping there would be a more "elegant" way. 

```
while read line
do
 region=`echo $line | awk -F',' '{ print $3 }'
 if [ $region == 'USA' ]
 then
  region_group=region1
 elif [ $region == 'UK' ]
 then
  region_group=region2
 etc. etc.
```

Comment: `sed -n '2,${s/Device/Region/;s/,[0-9][0-9]*,/=/p;}' file` works with the sample input and allows for Region number greater than 9. If you need to use the `ID` column to append to the `Region`, then its any easy fix of the regex. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I just deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
declare -A regions              # an associative array

# declare your variables
region1=USA
region2=UK
region3=Ireland

# associate each region's name with region's code
for i in "${!region@}"; do      # expands to region1, region2, region3
    varname="$i"
    regions[${!varname}]="$i"   # maps "USA" to "region1", "UK" to "region2" ..
done

while IFS=, read -r name id region; do
    ((nr++)) || continue        # skips the header line
    region_group="${regions[$region]}"
    echo "region=$region, region_group=$region_group"   # for a test
    # call API here
done < file.csv
```

Output:

```
region=USA, region_group=region1
region=UK, region_group=region2
region=Ireland, region_group=region3
```

BTW if the variable declaration at the beginning is under your control, it will be easier to say:

```
# declare an associative aarray
declare -A regions=(
    [USA]="region1"
    [UK]="region2"
    [Ireland]="region3"
)

while IFS=, read -r name id region; do
    ((nr++)) || continue        # skip the header line
    region_group="${regions[$region]}"
    echo "region=$region, region_group=$region_group"   # for a test
    # call API here
done < file.csv
```

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful and insightful. The headings in the csv had changed a bit, but I was able to adapt this to my needs. Thank you for explaining it properly as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use awk to create a lookup table.  eg:

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/sh

cat << EOD |
region1=USA
region2=UK
region3=Ireland
EOD
{
awk 'NR==FNR { lut[$2] = $1; next}
{$3 = lut[$3]} 1
' FS== /dev/fd/3 FS=, OFS=, - << EOF
Name,ID,Region
Device1,1,USA
Device2,2,UK
EOF
} 3<&0
$ ./a.sh
Name,ID,
Device1,1,region1
Device2,2,region2
```

or, slightly less obscure (and more portable to just use regular files, I'm not sure about the platforms on which `/dev/fd/3` is actually valid:

```
$ cat input
Name,ID,Region
Device1,1,USA
Device2,2,UK
$ cat lut
region1=USA
region2=UK
region3=Ireland
$ awk 'NR==FNR{lut[$2] = $1; next} {$3 = lut[$3]} 1' FS== lut FS=, OFS=, input
Name,ID,
Device1,1,region1
Device2,2,region2
```